# Change default GTK3/Glade label font size in Geany

Tags: gtk3, archlinux, glade, geany

I have been using the editor [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) on Arch Linux for quite a while now, however since the [last update](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/geany/) the font of the notebook tabs (located above the editor widget, [see a screenshot of Geany for reference here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Geany_Main.png)) is unnecessarily large (probably related to my HiDPI display).

Unfortunately, the GUI preferences menu does not provide any means to change the font size of the tabs. It only allows to change the font size of the editor, the symbol list (on the left) and the message widget (at the bottom).

After a quick look at the [geany source code](https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/src/notebook.c#L687) and the [associated glade configuration file](https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/master/data/geany.glade), it seems to me that Geany does not explicitly set a font size for these tab labels, but instead uses the default GTK3/Glade label size.

Is there a simple way, preferably without having to re-compile, to change the default font size for labels in a GTK3/Glade application, e.g. by changing some configuration files?